# Best way to make android app with python

Tags: android, python-3.x, apk, kivy, buildozer

I want to make a little game in python to run on android. Just for fun, and learning. 
I already made a "hello world" and compile an apk with buildozer + kivy. But waht is the best way to manage properly an apk application ?

Should i make my application with pygame, then when it's finish, compile it with buildozer ?

Or use kivy directly ? How to manage different screen sizze for example ?

It's higlty possible that i didn't understand all the possibilities with kivy. I just want to learn the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Kivy directly. I'm not sure there's any actively supported build tool for pygame apps on Android, and in any case Kivy's graphics apis are both performant and capable (and more modern than pygame's).